# Delete everything before a character on certain lines in a large text in OpenRefine

Tags: openrefine

I’ve looked around but did not find an answer.

I’m cleaning a large amount of texts in OpenRefine. What I am trying to do is to suppress lines—between two end of lines (\n)—containing a specific character—in this case %. It looks like this:

...En trois mots, la bouffe lyonnaise, ça se résume à quoi?\n« Réconfortante, savoureuse, chaleureuse. » \n \n**La quenelle de brochet et sa sauce aux écrevisses %**\nL'extra avec ça?\nLe chef Viola concoctera une soupe géante et celle-ci sera partagée GRATUITEMENT le samedi 25 février 2017! Stay tuned! \nLe bouchon lyonnais du Balmoral, c'est un rendez-vous! \nMontréal en Lumière - volet gastronomie\n23 février au 11 mars 2016 \nLE BALMORAL\n514 288-5992

I am looking for such result (without the bolded line):

...En trois mots, la bouffe lyonnaise, ça se résume à quoi?\n« Réconfortante, savoureuse, chaleureuse. » \n \n\nL'extra avec ça?\nLe chef Viola concoctera une soupe géante et celle-ci sera partagée GRATUITEMENT le samedi 25 février 2017! Stay tuned! \nLe bouchon lyonnais du Balmoral, c'est un rendez-vous! \nMontréal en Lumière - volet gastronomie\n23 février au 11 mars 2016 \nLE BALMORAL\n514 288-5992

This, for many instances in multiple texts.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about a specific programming problem as defined in the [help/on-topic]. This question might be appropriate for [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com), but please review their [help center](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help) before posting.

Comment: @IanCampbell although not phrased as a programming question, it actually is. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether the "\n" are literal or a representation of the LF character, but I'll assume the former and you can adjust the formula, if necessary. The solution involves splitting the lines, iterating through the lines and filtering the lines containing '%' and joining the lines again. Use the following formula in the "Edit Cells -> Transform" dialog:

`forEach(value.split('\\n'),l,if(l.contains('%'),'',l)).join('\\n')`

To break it down:

- `value.split('\\n')` yields an array of split lines
- `forEach(array,l,f)` iterates through the array assigning each line to the variable `l` and applying function `f`
- `if(l.contains('%'),'',l))` returns the empty string if `l` contains a percent ('%') otherwise the original string
- `array.join('\\n')` joins your filtered lines back together again

Comment: This works wonderfully. Your explanation is quite helpful too, and I thank you for that also.